# Mixed model with significant 2-way interaction, simple slopes not significant

Tags: mixed-model, interaction

I do have a question about interactions in mixed models when a categorical IV (3 levels) interacts with a continuous one.

But first, let me explain what I want and what I have done:

I have measured the reaction time (`rt`) of participants in three settings (`settings`; every participant had their reaction time measured in all three settings, which makes it a repeated measure). Also I have a continuous variable (`var`).

(Plus some other variables `x1`, `x2` and `x3` - but they are irrelevant for this question)

I want to know if there is an effect of setting on rt.
I want to know if there is an effect of var on rt.
I want to know if setting and var interact. And if so: Interpret the moderation.

My data looks like this:

```
head(data_long2)
```

```
  id setting x1 x2 x3 var       rt
1  4      S3 12 16  9   5 5.280574
2  4      S2 12 16  9   5 5.033336
3  4      S1 12 16  9   5 4.919734
4  5      S3 12  7  5   1 3.896618
5  5      S2 12  7  5   1 3.864561
6  5      S1 12  7  5   1 4.592544
```

I fitted the model with the participant id as random effect:

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

data_long2$setting <- relevel(data_long2$setting, ref="S1")

lmer.rt.full <- lmer(rt ~ setting*var + x1 + x2 + x3 + (1|id), data=data_long2, REML=FALSE)
summary(lmer.rt.full)
```

which gives me:

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: rt ~ setting * var + x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 | id)
   Data: data_long2

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   369.8    403.8   -173.9    347.8      151 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0100 -0.6783 -0.0073  0.6204  2.4142 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 0.1479   0.3845  
 Residual             0.3888   0.6235  
Number of obs: 162, groups:  id, 54

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     4.89742    0.21271  96.15014  23.024  < 2e-16 ***
settingS3      -0.93066    0.19375 108.00000  -4.804 5.05e-06 ***
settingS2      -0.70207    0.19375 108.00000  -3.624 0.000444 ***
var            -0.08678    0.04789 114.85395  -1.812 0.072572 .  
x1             -0.02308    0.02061  54.00000  -1.120 0.267794    
x2              0.02070    0.01404  54.00000   1.475 0.146147    
x3             -0.06759    0.02763  54.00000  -2.446 0.017725 *  
settingS3:var   0.12468    0.05009 108.00000   2.489 0.014328 *  
settingS2:var   0.17877    0.05009 108.00000   3.569 0.000536 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) sttnS3 sttnS2 var    x1     x2     x3     sttS3:
settingS3   -0.455                                                 
settingS2   -0.455  0.500                                          
var         -0.206  0.411  0.411                                   
x1          -0.148  0.000  0.000  0.012                            
x2          -0.247  0.000  0.000 -0.170 -0.302                     
x3          -0.409  0.000  0.000 -0.385 -0.166 -0.235              
settngS3:vr  0.358 -0.785 -0.393 -0.523  0.000  0.000  0.000       
settngS2:vr  0.358 -0.393 -0.785 -0.523  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.500
```

There's a significant difference compared to a stepped down model with no interaction term present:

```
lmer.rt.reduced <- lmer(rt ~ setting + var + x1 + x2 + x3 + (1|id), data=data_long2, REML=FALSE)
anova(lmer.rt.reduced, lmer.rt.full)
```

```
Data: data_long2
Models:
lmer.rt.reduced: rt ~ setting + var + x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 | id)
lmer.rt.full: rt ~ setting * var + x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 | id)
                Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)   
lmer.rt.reduced  9 378.42 406.21 -180.21   360.42                            
lmer.rt.full    11 369.79 403.75 -173.90   347.79 12.632      2   0.001807 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I then plot the interaction:

```
interact_plot(lmer.rt.full, pred=var, modx=setting, plot.points=FALSE)
```

Which in turn gives me:

[image: Interaction Plot]

From the plot I see that reaction time in setting 1 is higher for individuals high on var as opposed to individuals low on var. Same goes for setting 2. But in setting 3 people high on var will have lower reaction times than people low on var.

This makes sense to me (theory-wise).

But now: How do I interpret the interaction? From what I've understood I can say:

- There is an significant interaction
- The simple slopes of S2 and S3 for var differ significantly from S1

But if I want to interpret the interaction (as I have done before with the plot), I do need to test the simple slopes. Is that correct? If I do that with:

```
sim_slopes(lmer.rt.full, pred=var, modx=setting, johnson_neyman=FALSE)
```

I get no significant slopes at all:

```
SIMPLE SLOPES ANALYSIS 

Slope of var when setting = S2: 

  Est.   S.E.   t val.      p
------ ------ -------- ------
  0.09   0.05     1.92   0.06

Slope of var when setting = S3: 

  Est.   S.E.   t val.      p
------ ------ -------- ------
  0.04   0.05     0.79   0.43

Slope of var when setting = S1: 

   Est.   S.E.   t val.      p
------- ------ -------- ------
  -0.09   0.05    -1.81   0.07
```

What does that mean? Does it mean that I cannot say with certainty the slope for S1 is negative? Only that it does differ significantly from S2 and S3?
How should I report that?

Because the Beta of `var` (from `summary(lmer.rt.full)`) is not significant as well.

Comment: I don't think it is true. You're saying they are significantly different from each other, then you are testing if they are significantly different from zero.

Comment: @JeremyMiles What do you think is not true? Do you mean my last paragraph? Bust isn't it true that when the slopes are not significantly different from zero that I cannot interpret them as I did earlier (below the plotted interaction)? It would be really helpful for my thesis if I could for example conclude that in S1 ```rt``` will decrease for higher levels of ```var```.

Comment: But if I want to interpret the interaction (as I have done before with the plot), I do need to test the simple slopes. Is that correct? I don't think that's true. I think that because: The Difference Between “Significant” and “Not Significant” is not Itself Statistically Significant - http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/signif4.pdf

Comment: @JeremyMiles But then why test the slopes at all? Do I even have to?

Comment: Testing them helps with interpretation. It's a bit like testing if group A is different from group B, and finding that significant. Then testing whether group A is different from zero and group B is different from zero. If you know that group A and B are different from each other, you don't care all that much if they are different from zero.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Ah, now I see - that makes sense to me. So, thanks! Oh and by the way, thanks for your books too. I have a copy of Discovering statistics using R - which I really like.